# Booking System Efficient Way to Make Rooms Unavailable

Tags: sql, database

I am creating a booking system:

**Customer**
cust_id, 
cust_name, 
cust_etc.....

**Room**
room_id,
room_name,
room_etc

**Booking**
booking_id,
room_no,
cust_no
arrive_date,
depart_date

The booking table will allow me to only show availability on a calendar.  The problem is I want to block certain periods of time off from being booked. The only way I can see would be to put an entry in the booking table but not assign a cust_id.  I would be grateful if someone could tell me if this is the best and most efficient way.

Comment: What if you create a calendar with availability records, and possible pricing information. A booking would then related to a customer, room, and calendar?

Comment: The simplest and safest way would be to add a "dummy" customer (call it managment or something like that) and just use this customer id whenever a room is closed for actual booking

Comment: @ZoharPeled - the only downside is you will have to hardcode to exclude this "dummy" customer from any reports or automated processes. It is bad practise. The issue can be resolved easily with a correct design/schema.

Comment: First, the design seems fine. Second, there are easy ways to exclude this customer from reports. Do you have a better suggestion? Share it!

Comment: There is a calendar that loops through the days of the year, as the days are generated on the calendar a check is made to make sure its not booked in the booking table. If it is its marked as booked.  Prices are also added in a separate table called cost with date, room_id,  and cost.  This is used to show a price on the calendar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest doing it the following way:

1. Create a table that will store dates in which any booking should not be available. Let's call it `booking_prevention`.
   Extra value: I suggest adding a description column that would hold detail about undergoing events in that time.
2. Create a trigger that would prevent adding a new record to booking table, if dates overlaps with those from table `booking_prevention`.

Sample schema:

**Booking:** *booking_id, room_no, cust_no arrive_date, depart_date*

**Booking_prevention:** *bk_prev_id, date_start, date_end, description*

Testing with PostgreSQL:

```
-- Creating a function that would go through every record in booking_prevention table
CREATE FUNCTION trg_prevent_booking ()
RETURNS TRIGGER
STABLE
AS $$
DECLARE 
    r record; 
BEGIN
FOR r IN 
    SELECT date_start, date_end FROM booking_prevention 
LOOP 
    IF ((NEW.arrive_date, NEW.depart_date) OVERLAPS (r.date_start, r.date_end)) 
    THEN 
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'You can not book a room on those days! Check booking_prevention table for details'
    END IF; 
END LOOP; 
RETURN NEW;
END;        
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- Creating a trigger that fires for each row on booking
CREATE TRIGGER prevent_booking BEFORE INSERT ON booking FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_prevent_booking();
```

Values inside `booking_prevention` table:

```
SELECT * FROM booking_prevention;

 id | date_start |  date_end  | description |
----+------------+------------+--------------
  1 | 2015-06-10 | 2015-06-20 | Maintenance |
```

Testing with new bookings:

```
INSERT INTO booking VALUES (default, 5, 1001, '2015-06-03', '2015-06-11');
ERROR:  You can not book a room on those days! Check booking_prevention table for details

INSERT INTO booking VALUES (default, 5, 1001, '2015-06-03', '2015-06-09');
INSERT 0 1
```

Think about optimizing the function. A good way to start, would be to limit the rows a record would have to loop through every time a trigger fires.

In an error message you could also put the value from description. Adjust it to your needs.

**EDIT**

This section was added after OP comment worrying about efficiency.

A good way to keep your `booking_prevention` table small and the lookup efficient would be to create a table, that would hold records from prevention table which have their `date_end < current_date`. Those records are no longer needed to be checked, assuming that you are not allowing your system to book rooms in the past (which is fair assumption, I guess).

This approach would be useful as long as you need to store details about prevention dates in the past. If that's not the case - you could always remove then from your `booking_prevention` table.

Comment: What you have said about creating a table to store prevented dates makes sense, thank you.  I use php and MySQL via phpmyadmin, so I am not sure how functions work.  However this is something that I can code, though it may not be as efficient.

Comment: @simmo without adding dummy values or changing your schema, I believe this is the way to go. I edited my answer with some more tips as far as efficiency is concerned.